# Creating tun/tap devices on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I am trying to create tap devices on the host machine using the command:

```
sudo ip tuntap add mode tap br0p0
```

but I get the following error message:

```
Object "tuntap" is unknown, try "ip help".
```

What should I do? I am working on Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your command is correct, the problem is your version of `ip` is lacking support for `tuntap`. In Ubuntu 10.04 you will need to use [tunctl](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tunctl) unfortunately, or else time for a dist-upgrade! tuntap support was added to IP from Maverick (Ubuntu 10.10).

You can verify this by doing `ip help` and looking at the line that looks like:

> where  OBJECT := { link | addr | addrlabel | route | rule | neigh | ntable |
>                      tunnel | tuntap | maddr | mroute | monitor | xfrm }

If you don't see tuntap, you're going to be needing tunctl I'm afraid!

You would use `tunctl -p -t br0p0` for a TAP interface or `tunctl -n -t br0p0` to create a TUN interface. Then obviously the usual ifconfig/router commands to get the interface up.

Have a scan over the [tunctl man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tunctl) for some worked examples.

Comment: How can I write the same command with tunctl?

Comment: I;ve updated my answer to include the equivalents.